# How do I create an Arduino UNO using Eagle PCB designer?

Tags: arduino

I am just starting with PCB designing.
I recently downloaded CadSoft Eagle and was thinking it better to first start with Arduino UNO.

Comment: That isn't a programming question. Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're just starting out, you don't want to try as complex a design as a MCU development board. Especially not with EAGLE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronic design

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of PCB design.  PCB design is almost a "Trade skill" - sometimes more art than science, so to speak - it will take you some time to build your skill, but it's well worth it.

Beginning by producing existing designs is a good idea.  Part of the learning process of designing PCB's isn't just getting the design correct on paper, but learning how to work with the PCB manufacturer after your design is finished.  Almost always, the PCB manufacturer will take your design and then want to make further changes to make your design "manufacturable".  More often than not the output from CAD programs is not "manufacturer read" and will require some post-design tweaking by the PCB manufacturer.

Starting with the Arduino UNO is not a bad idea.  The Arduino is quasi-open source hardware.  Provided that you respect their brand name and don't try to re-sell their items without proper licensing, you are allowed to copy and produce as many Arduino UNO's for personal use as you want.  You just can't commercially sell them without getting licensed by Arduino company.

Surf to the official Arduino website, go to this page https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno and scroll down and click on the "Eagle Files in .ZIP" link to download the "Sort of" open-source hardware files.

Stack Exchange/Overflow will not answer any questions like "which CAD package is best", but in this case since Arduino is offering the files in EagleCAD format, I would suggest you start out with EagleCAD.  You can export EagleCAD format to other CAD packages, but that is well beyond the scope for a beginner.  You can download EagleCAD at the official website http://www.cadsoftusa.com/

Once you get Eagle installed and download the .ZIP file let us know, we can work on next steps to open the project for the first time.  Basically you can unzip the files into EagleCAD's project folder, go to EagleCAD, and try opening the .brd or .sch file.

There is a .brd file which represents the physical layout of the board, but there is also .sch schematic file which represents the electrical schematic and all the connections.  The .brd file and the .sch file need to stay "consistent" so that EagleCAD can do error checking between the two.  For example if you place a resistor in the schematic and connect signals to it, EagleCAD will expect you to have a resistor and electrical copper traces over on the .brd file that are "consistent" with what you put on the schematic.  ALWAYS heed any warnings where it says .brd and .sch are not consistent - these MUST be consistent, must must must.

Get started and post back, we can help you work towards producing the output files needed to send to a PCB manufacturer to produce your first PCB.  There are many affordable low-quantity fast-turn prototype PCB companies that can help you product your first PCB.

Answer (score 0):

first Draw the Schematic Drawing.Then import it to layout  and start routing.
You can also download eagle file directly from this link

[Eagle file for Arduino UNO](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno#.Uw7JxeOSz3U)

[Schematic of arduino UNO](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf)